# Imgur returning 500 Internal Server Error for binary body

Tags: java, post, binaryfiles, imgur

I'm trying to upload images to the imgur api. It returns a 500 error when trying to upload a binary body. However uploading it as base64 works fine.

I've also tried to do the requests with [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) and those worked just fine.

I'm really not sure why i'm getting a 500 though. That would indicate it's on imgurs end but I don't quite believe thats the case since it works fine in Insomnia and as base64.

[image: Example in Insomnia]

I've read the following post: [How to upload to Imgur (API v3) using binary format of image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26343535/how-to-upload-to-imgur-api-v3-using-binary-format-of-image)
But it only seems to cover `Files` and not byte arrays.

The Base uploader class. Essentially an abstract class with basic uploading functionality.

```java
//imports in case they're needed
import me.darkeyedragon.imageutils.client.ImageUtilsMain;
import org.apache.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

...

public BaseUploader(ExecutorService executorService) {
    httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    params = new ArrayList<>(1);
    httpPost = new HttpPost();
    this.executorService = executorService;
    builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    httpPost.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "image/png");
    httpPost.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "text/html,json");
    httpPost.addHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, ImageUtilsMain.getModId() + "/" + ImageUtilsMain.getVersion());
}


@Override
public HttpResponse upload(BufferedImage bufferedImage) throws IOException {
    final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", baos);
    final byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
    baos.flush();
    baos.close();
    httpPost.setEntity(builder.addBinaryBody("image", imageInByte).build());
    //addParam("image", Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageInByte));
    return httpClient.execute(httpPost);
}
...
```

the imgur uploader class:

```
public class ImgurUploader extends BaseUploader {

    public ImgurUploader(ImageUtilsMain main) {
        super("https://api.imgur.com/3/image", main.getUploadHandler().getFixedThreadPool());
        super.getHttpPost().addHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Client-ID <my id>");
    }
}
```

Not sure what i'm doing wrong here. Am I using the wrong builder? Am i forgetting to set some header parameters?